# How to run exe stored on shared drive using process task in SSIS

Tags: ssis

In my SSIS package I need to execute exe which is stored on shared drive example "\abc.test.com\myfolder".

I am using "process task" and providing working directory as "\abc.test.com\myfolder" and executable as "myfile.exe"

When I run the package it opens console and does nothing. Package shows error "The process exit code was "-1073741510".

Comment: My assumption is that the process running the package does not have access to the shared drive. Whether the fix is to add a credentialed user and a proxy for a job running the ssis package or modify the SQL Agent service account to have access etc is likely a big question

Comment: I am running it on my machine and I have access to shared drive.

Comment: But is SQL Server and/or Agent running under your credentials or Network Services or something else. We need more info to be able to diagnose your problem

Answer (score 1):

You could use a C# Script Task in your SSIS Package

Add `using System.Diagnostics;`

And then do something like

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"C:\App\MyAwesomeExe.exe");
int id = process.Id;
Process tempProc = Process.GetProcessById(id);
this.Visible = false;
tempProc.WaitForExit();
this.Visible = true;
```